# Loop through filenames in a folder in Windows and send each name to ffmpeg command

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, cygwin

In windows I want to create a batch file which given a specific directory will loop through all the names of the files and pass each of them to a command, ffmpeg in my case. I found two or three examples of ffmpeg being used to loop through a folder, but they were all in Linux. For the time being I use a python script to do so:

```
import os
import subprocess

sourcedir = "G:\Animation\Anime\OnePiece\Episodes\Main"
outputdir = "G:\Animation\Anime\OnePiece\Episodes\Converted"

for file in os.listdir(sourcedir):
    name = file[:file.rfind(".")]
    subprocess.call("ffmpeg -i " + sourcedir + "\\" + name + ".mkv -s 640x480 -map 0 -vcodec libx265 "+ outputdir + "\\" + name + ".mkv")
```

Even if running it directly through a Windows batch file instead of via Python decreases the time needed to encode a video by 10 seconds, it will literally save me hours.

And just a thought, will it be any better using the bash commands on Cygwin?

Comment: What you need is a `for` loop -- open a command prompt window, type `for /?` and read the help text...

Comment: I highly doubt it will make ffmpeg run faster.  Does not matter if python or cmd.exe spawns the process, ffmpeg is still going to run the same.

Comment: @aschipfl
i know what a for loop is but i dont know cmd/batch programming, can you please share a syntax to extract all file names one by name and transferring them to a command ??

Comment: @Squashman
It did, I ran the same encodings twice, once with python and once directly, it took exactly 12.56 seconds less.

Comment: @daddyodevil running something twice is not good enough of a comparison.  At any given time I have all kinds of automated stuff running on my computers that could slow down the overall processing of anything.  I have python installed but not ffmpeg, nor do I have any files to convert. But if I every do I will test it out and see.  Python has always been very fast all the times I have used it.  Especially compared against the .NET crap that some of our programmers use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you close.  I am not really understanding the syntax of ffmpeg.

```
 @echo off
 set "sourcedir=G:\Animation\Anime\OnePiece\Episodes\Main"
 set "outputdir=G:\Animation\Anime\OnePiece\Episodes\Converted"

 PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

 for %%F in (*.mkv) DO ffmpeg -i "%%F" -s 640x480 -map 0 -vcodec libx265 "%outputdir%\%%F"

 POPD
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot. It helped me